# Control particular block of code in Jmeter to stop and start new thread?

Tags: jmeter

Threads: 1000

```
1. Validate username
2. Validate Password
If controller
    3. User Info
    4. Settings
    5. Payments
    etc...
    20. Logout
```

Now if Validate Password is failed then the subsequent run will be not run.. But still thread is counted.. Consider 800 is success and 200 login is failing still it shows Active 1000 Started: 1000.

I dont want the thread which is failed on validate password, How to stop the thread which is failed and instead getting new thread..

In Thread groups, there is setting "`Action to be taken after a sampler error`"

I have selected `Start Next Thread Loop`. so that if it fails on Validate login, should start new thread. But It also create new thread, if there is a fail on the if loop block. that is actual application failure.

I wanted stop current thread start new thread on fail of validate username and password call `but if it is failed on the if block it should report error not stop and start new thread.`

Is it possible? Because thread group controls whole group of test?

Answer (score 0):

You can create new thread in [JSR223 component](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor), but *use it carefully*

```
ctx.getThreadGroup().addNewThread( 0, ctx.getEngine() )
```

You can stop in specific case using [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) using Stop Actions:

> The "Stop" action stops the thread or test after completing any samples that are in progress. The "Stop Now" action stops the test without waiting for samples to complete